# Wine install from source while keeping brew installed version

Tags: homebrew, wine

I have wine 1.6.2 installed currently through brew running Yosemite 10.10.2. I would like to simultaneously have an older version of wine on my machine to run a program that does not work with newer versions of wine. The version of wine I need is not available through `brew versions wine` so I will need to build from source if possible. I need to try with a number of versions of wine from before version 1.2. Can this be done and how do I make both versions of wine available and prevent naming conflicts etc. ?

Comment: When asking questions such as this it might be helpful if you include both the OS X version you're using and what version of Wine you're wanting to install.

Comment: The latest OS X version that supports Wine 1.2 is Leopard.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the info. This is gonna be interesting :)